# How can I do to get the keys which are integers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like that:

```
a = {1: 'a', 5: 'b', 'h': 'c'}
```

And I wanted to get in a list all the keys which are integers, I mean something like that:

```
d = [1, 5]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension to filter out the keys which are not integers as below:

```
d = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo You're right, .keys() is not necessary. Editing the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
a = {1: 'a', 5: 'b', 'h': 'c'}
d = []
for key in a:
    if type(key) is int:
        d.append(key)
        
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this task. A simple code snippet to solve this is as follows: `d = [k for k in a.keys() if type(k) == int]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, and `isinstance` to filter out the integer keys.

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), a.keys()))
[1, 5]
```